# Raspberry Pi Micro SD keeps getting corrupt

Tags: pi-4

I see that this question has been asked a few other times but those seem different to my situation.

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B 2GB which is running pretty much in a standard configuration (i.e. no overclocking etc., running in the official case with the official power supply). After about a month of use it stopped working (commands like sudo would throw errors, I couldn't reboot via any of the commands) and finally I physically pulled the plug and put it back only to see it complaining about a corrupt Micro SD upon boot. Thinking it's probably a one-off I switched to a new Micro SD card and also changed the power supply to a different point which has surge protection etc.

After about two weeks - today - this card too has failed with similar errors.

Is this just a case of a faulty board that seems to corrupt Micro SD cards, so I should simply cut my losses and get a new Pi? Or is there anything else I can look at - e.g. buy a new power supply adapter (that's all I can think of). I know I could just try a new power supply adapter but I am not too keen on doing this and waiting a few weeks just in case the Pi fails again. :-/

Regards,
Rakhesh

Updates:

1. The first Micro SD was a 16 GB Panasonic. The second was a 64 GB Kingston.
2. No heavy IO. I run Docker on it, but don't build anything on it. I have a couple of containers running on it (nothing fancy - DNS, a web server for my own home use).
3. What happens is that things stop working on the Pi. None of the commands work. Once I reboot I get an error that the Micro SD is corrupt (sorry I don't remm the exact error message but I can check and provide if that helps).

Comment: You need to give far more information about what is happening on the Pi.

Comment: Can you update your question to provide details about the microSD card? (Size, Brand, etc.) and also what is the nature of the workload running on the Pi (does it perform heavy amounts of I/O to the card?)

Comment: It doesn't sound normal.   If you do decide to go the replacement route, you should contact the distributor and try and arrange it under warranty, I think 1 year is standard (but I think it is the distributor that does this); some places it is required by law.